# CircleCI 1.0→2.0 へ　config.yml ファイルの修正の仕方を教えてほしい

Tags: circleci

CircleCI1.0　の　config.yml  は下記のようになっており、　2.0用の変換ツールを作って作成してみたいのですが、バージョンは2.0になったのですが、

コミットの内容が開発環境,本番へ反映されません。　どこを修正したらよいでしょうか？

【CircleCI1.0のconfig.yml】

```
machine:
  timezone:
    Asia/Tokyo
  ruby:
    version: x.x.2

  php:
    version: x.x.15

  hosts:
    dev.example.com: xxx.0.0.1

test:
  override:
    - exit 0

deployment:
  production:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - bundle exec cap production deploy
  staging:
    branch: develop
    commands:
      - bundle exec cap development deploy
```

【CircleCI2.0のconfig.yml】 これが内容がサイトへ反映されない（CircleCI2.0のErrorは出ない）

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    parallelism: 1
    shell: /bin/bash --login

    environment:
      CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS: /tmp/circleci-artifacts
      CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS: /tmp/circleci-test-results

    docker:
    - image: circleci/build-image:ubuntu-14.04-XXL-upstart-1189-5614f37
      command: /sbin/init
    steps:

    - run:
        working_directory: ~/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx
        command: 'echo ''Asia/Tokyo'' | sudo tee -a /etc/timezone; sudo dpkg-reconfigure
          -f noninteractive tzdata; sudo service mysql restart; sudo service postgresql
          restart; '
    - run:
        working_directory: ~/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx
        command: rm -f ~/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.rvmrc; echo 2.1.2 > ~/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.ruby-version; rvm use 2.1.2 --default
    - run:
        working_directory: ~/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx
        command: |-
          ln -fs << $HOME/.phpenv/versions/x.x.15/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
          phpenv global x.x.15 2>/dev/null
    - run:
        working_directory: ~/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx
        command: |-
          printf 'xxx.0.0.1       dev.example.com
          ' | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts

    - restore_cache:
        keys:

        - v1-dep-

    - run: composer install --no-interaction
    - run: echo -e "export RAILS_ENV=test\nexport RACK_ENV=test" >> $BASH_ENV
    - run: 'bundle check --path=vendor/bundle || bundle install --path=vendor/bundle
        --jobs=4 --retry=3 '

    - save_cache:
        key: v1-dep-{{ .Branch }}-{{ epoch }}
        paths:

        - vendor/bundle
        - ~/virtualenvs
        - ~/.m2
        - ~/.ivy2
        - ~/.bundle
        - ~/.go_workspace
        - ~/.gradle
        - ~/.cache/bower

    - run: exit 0

    - store_test_results:
        path: /tmp/circleci-test-results

    - store_artifacts:
        path: /tmp/circleci-artifacts
    - store_artifacts:
        path: /tmp/circleci-test-results
```

Comment: > `コミットの内容がdeploymenｔ,masterへ反映されません。`  `これが内容がサイトへ反映されない（CircleCI2.0のErrorは出ない）` とありますが、どちらが本題でしょうか（両方でしょうか？）

Comment: 質問ありがとうございます。コミットの内容が開発環境,本番へ反映されません。どこを修正したらよいでしょうか？になります。

Answer (score 1):

CircleCI1.0版で実行されていたデプロイ部分が欠落しているのが原因になります。

該当箇所としては以下になり、

```
deployment:
  production:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - bundle exec cap production deploy
  staging:
    branch: develop
    commands:
      - bundle exec cap development deploy
```

この `bundle exec cap 環境 deploy` という部分が実際にサイトにデプロイしているコマンドになります。これがCircleCI2.0では存在しないため、反映されていないのかと存じます。

#### 追記 2019-03-25T17:37:09+09:00

このため、CircleCI2.0用にデプロイ処理を入れる必要があります。 `run` とは異なり、 `deploy` というコマンドを使うと並列性があがるのでこれを利用しつつデプロイの仕組みを入れましょう。

[Configuring CircleCI - CircleCI](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#deploy)

CircleCI1.0とCircleCI2.0の記載内容が大幅に異なり、どのように修正すればよいかは答えづらいですが、以下のような内容をビルドなど修正したステップに挿入するとデプロイが出来るようになると思います。

```
- deploy:
    command: |
        bundle exec cap development deploy
```

Comment: 2.0用の書き方をご存知でしょうか？？　1.0と異なるようです。

Comment: 追記致しましたので、ご確認ください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。　しかし、動きません。

Comment: 動かないというのは、エラーが出ているという意味でしょうか。それとも、正常に終了しているにも関わらずデプロイされないという意味でしょうか。

Comment: 正常に終了しているにも関わらずデプロイされないません。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。